# How to change the size of the indent that's created using ">" (forward arrow)?

Tags: vimrc, indentation, tab-characters

If I want to change the tab size, I can do that with `set tabstop=<number>`. I have that in my .vimrc to make it 4 instead of 8.

However, when I indent/deindent text by highlighting it then using `>`, it still uses the default tab size of 8. How can I make this be 4 too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`:h >`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3E):

```
                                                        <
 >{motion}              Shift {motion} lines one 'shiftwidth' rightwards.
                                                        >>
 >>                     Shift [count] lines one 'shiftwidth' rightwards.
```

So you need to set [`shiftwidth`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27shiftwidth%27) to affect this:

```
set shiftwidth=4
" or, to use the value of 'tabstop'
set shiftwidth=0
```

Comment: Ok, I see it now, in the documentation for shiftwidth. When shiftwidth is 0, it uses the value for tab stop. All right, thanks a lot.